# Sphinx: Indexer causes MySQL to hang

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

Not sure what's going on. I run indexer --all --rotate
When it finishes mysql hangs and not accepting new connections. 
from my observation as soon as indexer finishes, all `update,insert,delete` queries goes into `query end` state

*mysql tables are not corrupt

*i'm using Percona mysql 5.6.12-56

*table in Innodb type

*tried to install sphinx from source and rpm, also tried Sphinx 2.1.1 and Sphinx 2.0.8

```
indexer --all --rotate
Sphinx 2.1.1-beta (rel21-r3701)
Copyright (c) 2001-2013, Andrew Aksyonoff
Copyright (c) 2008-2013, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)

using config file '/etc/sphinx/sphinx.conf'...
indexing index 'online'...
collected 27114 docs, 99.0 MB
sorted 258.8 Mhits, 100.0% done
total 27114 docs, 98993190 bytes
total 119.609 sec, 827633 bytes/sec, 226.68 docs/sec
total 21 reads, 4.497 sec, 53362.9 kb/call avg, 214.1 msec/call avg
total 2510 writes, 3.210 sec, 968.1 kb/call avg, 1.2 msec/call avg
rotating indices: successfully sent SIGHUP to searchd (pid=12773).
```

processlist when it hangs:

```
    Id  User    Host    db  Command Time    State   Info    Rows_sent   Rows_examined
    31891   forum_DB        localhost   forum_DB        Query   346     query end   INSERT INTO ibf_sessions (`id`,`member_name`,`member_id$
    31905   forum_DB        localhost   forum_DB        Query   346     query end   DELETE FROM ibf_sessions WHERE (id='yandex=95108240250_$
    31964   forum_DB        localhost   forum_DB        Query   345     query end   INSERT INTO ibf_sessions (`id`,`member_name`,`member_id$
    32062   forum_DB        localhost   forum_DB        Query   343     query end   INSERT INTO ibf_topic_views (`views_tid`) VALUES(599181$
    32077   forum_DB        localhost   forum_DB        Query   343     query end   INSERT INTO ibf_topic_views (`views_tid`) VALUES(599181$
    32353   forum_DB        localhost   forum_DB        Query   338     query end   INSERT INTO ibf_core_like_cache (`like_cache_id`,`like_$
    32443   forum_DB        localhost   forum_DB        Query   336     query end   INSERT INTO ibf_core_like_cache (`like_cache_id`,`like_$
    32450   forum_DB        localhost   forum_DB        Query   336     query end   INSERT INTO ibf_sessions (`id`,`member_name`,`member_id$
    32518   forum_DB        localhost   forum_DB        Query   335     query end   INSERT INTO ibf_sessions (`id`,`member_name`,`member_id$
    32617   forum_DB        localhost   forum_DB        Query   333     query end   INSERT INTO ibf_core_like_cache (`like_cache_id`,`like_$
    32642   forum_DB        localhost   forum_DB        Query   332     query end   INSERT INTO ibf_sessions (`id`,`member_name`,`member_i
...
37207   online  localhost   online  Query   247     Waiting for query cache lock    SELECT id, short_story, title, date, alt_name, category$
37216   forum_DB        localhost   forum_DB        Query   247     query end   INSERT INTO ibf_sessions (`id`,`member_name`,`member_id$
37228   online  localhost   online  Query   247     Waiting for query cache lock    SELECT id, short_story, title, date, alt_name, category$
37232   online  localhost   online  Query   247     System lock     SELECT id, autor, date, short_story, SUBSTRING(full_story, 1, 15) as fu$
37239   online  localhost   online  Query   247     FULLTEXT initialization SELECT id, short_story, title, date, alt_name, category, flag F$
37243   music   localhost   music   Query   247     Waiting for query cache lock    TRUNCATE TABLE dle_login_log    0   0
37250   online  localhost   online  Query   246     Sending data    SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM dle_post WHERE approve=1 AND allow_main=1$
37253   files   localhost   files   Query   246     Waiting for query cache lock    TRUNCATE TABLE dle_views        0   0
37264   music   localhost   music   Query   246     Waiting for table metadata lock TRUNCATE TABLE dle_login_log    0   0
37271   files   localhost   files   Query   245     Waiting for table metadata lock SELECT COUNT(*) as count, news_id FROM dle_views GROUP $
37279   online  localhost   online  Query   245     Sending data    SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM dle_post WHERE approve=1 AND allow_main=1$
37288   files   localhost   files   Query   244     Waiting for table metadata lock SELECT COUNT(*) as count, news_id FROM dle_views GROUP $
37289   online  localhost   online  Query   244     FULLTEXT initialization SELECT id, short_story, title, date, alt_name, category, flag F$
37291   files   localhost   files   Query   244     Waiting for table metadata lock SELECT COUNT(*) as count, news_id FROM dle_views GROUP $
37292   online  localhost   online  Query   244     Waiting for query cache lock    TRUNCATE TABLE dle_login_log    0   0
37296   online  localhost   online  Query   244     Sending data    SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM dle_post WHERE approve=1 AND
...
```

cat  processlist-2013-08-25-11-52.log | wc -l
352

sphinx.conf

```
source online_posts
{
        type                    = mysql

        sql_host                = 
        sql_user                = 
        sql_pass                = 
        sql_db                  = online_test
        sql_port                = 3306  # optional, default is 3306

        sql_query               = \
                SELECT * FROM post

        #sql_attr_uint          = group_id
        sql_attr_timestamp  = date

        sql_query_pre = SET NAMES utf8
        sql_query_pre = SET CHARACTER SET utf8
        sql_query_pre = SET SESSION query_cache_type=OFF

        sql_query_info          = SELECT * FROM post WHERE id=$id
}

index online
{
        source                  = online_posts
        path                    = /var/lib/sphinx/online
        docinfo                 = extern
        charset_type            = utf-8
        morphology              = stem_enru

        min_word_len            = 2
        min_prefix_len          = 0
        min_infix_len           = 2

        charset_table = 0..9, A..Z->a..z, _, a..z, U+410..U+42F->U+430..U+44F, U+430..U+44F

        enable_star = 1
}

indexer
{
    mem_limit       = 512M
}


searchd
{
    listen          = 9312
    listen          = 9306:mysql41
    log         = /var/log/sphinx/searchd.log
    query_log       = /var/log/sphinx/query.log
    read_timeout        = 5
    max_children        = 30
    pid_file        = /var/run/sphinx/searchd.pid
    max_matches     = 1000
    seamless_rotate     = 1
    preopen_indexes     = 1
    unlink_old      = 1
    workers         = threads # for RT to work
    binlog_path     = /var/lib/sphinx/
}
```

every time i run indexer i get the following in
/var/log/mysql.log

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%$
syntax error, unexpected '-', expecting FTS_TEXT or FTS_TERM or FTS_NUMB or '('
syntax error, unexpected '-', expecting FTS_TEXT or FTS_TERM or FTS_NUMB or '('
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%$
```

Looks like others have this problem as well, but I don't understand how he solved that
http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=11072

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I spending all day on it, it turns-out to be `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1`
setting `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0` fixed the problem.